# JavaScript API design examples

Tags: javascript, api

I'm designing a JavaScript API and am looking for outstanding examples.  Please point out libraries whose API you like, one answer per library.  If you don't mind, a comment explaining why you think it's good would be useful.

Also, please upvote existing answers if you agree that some library that's already posted is good.

Update: I'm looking for APIs which do their job well (though that job could be niche), which are a pleasure to use, involved a good learning curve, had great documentation/test coverage, result in simple client code for common cases, or similar.    I'm not necessarily looking for an API that does some inconceivably awesome thing like Cappuccino or JS/UIX.

Comment: Outstanding in terms of the *API*? Or in terms of *usefulness*? There's a subtle difference there. For example I love jQuery for it's usefulness, but dislike its API.

Comment: What does "JavaScript API" mean here? What's it supposed to do? Are we talking about things that provide convenient Ajax support, or abstract over cross-browser DOM issues, or something else? "API" is a bit vague.

Comment: @Rob -- since the question is about designing an API, maybe it doesn't matter. It sounds like the asker is looking for examples of libraries which are good examples of best practices.  Then again, that's just my interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript library I use most is JQuery (http://jquery.com/). I like it because it hides lots of browser-specific issues, allows people that don't know much about UI (such as myself) to do a decent job, and the syntax that results in using it is very clean and concise. Specifically, the API for selecting elements from the DOM is very clean. To get the element whose ID is foo, its simply $("#foo").